# Avoiding getting cached website version with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, parsing, caching, httpwebrequest, browser-cache

I need to parse one website which periodically publishes news on it, however very often I am getting old cached version.

I am using HttpWebRequest and tried

1. Appending "?dummy=345" to end of url
2. NativeMethods.DeleteUrlCacheEntry(requestUrl)
3. Setting HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore CachePolicy
4. Setting CacheControl, Pragma, IfModifiedSince headers

It all doesn't help. Most probably website runs some caching service which prevents me to get latest version realtime. Is there any work around?

I am running this parser on different machines in different regions and it is returning new version of the website with 0-3min delay. One machine can get new version 2min before another. All machines are querying website every second. Therefore I am convinced there is some caching going on.

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` doesn't cache anything by default. Show the code. "Use cache" answer is `304 Not Modified`. You probably receive 200. Can you tell, how did you determined that cache was used and how it works in the regular browser. Probably you may provide the real link to that site to reproduce the issue.

Comment: `[HttpWebRequest].Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");`. Also add `[HttpWebRequest].Headers.Add("DNT", "1");` if you need to set the `UserAgent` property.

Comment: @Jimi just interesting, how `DNT` can help here? And how it related to `User-Agent`?

Comment: @aepot updated the description, thanks

Comment: @Jimi could you please clarify how can DNT help? thanks

Comment: Are you using some external proxy? Proxy may cache the response.

Comment: @aepot not using proxy

Comment: It's not related to caching, it's related to the process to which a page *may* undergo before is handed to you and the scripts that *may* be active. -- Verify whether you receive a *cached* response or you receive an incomplete page, since of course, WebRequest does not process scripts. A URL to test would be better.

Comment: @Jimi can you please let me know how can I test it myself?

Comment: *I need to parse one website which periodically publishes news on it, however very often I am getting old cached version*. It looks like you have already tested it. Do you mean you receive *old versions* erratically? A WebRequest, usually, doesn't receive cached content, since there's no underlying cache system and the cookies are not stored. It *may* happen, sometimes, due to specific activity of a server (load balancers also). As mentioned, you should provide a test URL.